# How to access variables in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get access to a property contained inside my user object. 
My user model `has_many: posts`. In the controller how would i gain access to these posts? Would i create a method in the model?

```
def posts
  @posts = Post.find(User_id: params[:id])
end
```

or can i directly access the posts for the user. `User.posts` Since i am currently residing in the controller, is the controller aware of the currently selected model? Or do i have to pull the information again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the database for all the posts with a specific user_id, like this:

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:id])
```

Alternatively, you can find the user first and then fetch all posts associated with that user, like this:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
@posts = user.posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your id in params is the id of your user, you can use `user = User.find(params[:id])` to get the user and `@posts = user.posts` to get all the posts of this user.

Answer (score 0):

So, it is not about where you are, It is about what you are calling.

I'm sure you are familiar with relationships...

When you have relationships, it means that you can get to one relation from the other through whatever association exists between them.

> If I am my father's son, then you can get me directly by checking my father's children. ( you don't necessarily have to get all children in the village first )

So, bringing all my story above together, with the association between your  `Post` and `User`, you can always call `user.posts` (`user` being an instance of `User`) and `post.user` ( with `post` being an instance of `Post`)

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby on Rails guides have a section on associations, which is what you want. It's here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

In a nutshell, because you have added an association in your user model to a number of post records, Rails will build a helper method in your user model called posts. You can use that to access all the posts associated with that user.

When you create a post, the post record needs to have a column called user_id. This will provide the 'physical' link between the user and post models. You can access the posts from a user like so:

```
user.posts each do |post|
    # do something with post.content
end
```

To get posts that match some criteria in the posts collection you can query like this:

```
posts = user.posts.where(:something => 'matches criteria')
```

If you know there's only one post that matches the criteria, you can do this:

```
post = user.posts.where(:something => 'matches criteria').first
```

The post model also needs a belongs_to :user association. (The belongs_to will generate a helper method called user in the post model which you can then use to access the user record from the post.) For example:

```
user_email = post.user.email
```

The user record does not require a post_id column since Rails knows that user.post refers to the post table and automagically generates a query using user_id.

Anyway, the guide I linked to above will give you all the information you need and more too.